# Python Pygame Syntax errors, that have never before happened

Tags: python, pygame

I am getting a syntax error, I have searched for many hours on why this is happening but I cannot seem to find a reason. I am getting sytax errors on:

```
# -- Pictures ---
image[5] = (r"E5")
```

and on

```
# --- Colours ---
black = (0,0,0)
```

Any help is appreciated as I have never had this problem before with those specific pieces of code

```
# --- Import ---
import sys
import random
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

# --- Constants ---
size = width, height = 720, 480
speed = [2, 2]

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.display.set_caption("Broom! || BETA::00.1.0")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

car_width = 100

largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',115)
smallText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",20)

# --- Pictures ---
road = pygame.image.load(r"1.png")
BackgroundPNG = pygame.image.load(r"BackgroundPNG.png")
carImg = pygame.image.load(r"Sp1.png").convert_alpha()
image[1] = pygame.image.load(r"E1.png")
image[2] = pygame.image.load(r"E2.png")
image[3] = pygame.image.load(r"E3.png")
image[4] = pygame.image.load(r"E4.png"
image[5] = pygame.image.load(r"E5.png")

# --- Colours ---
black = (0,0,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
green = (0,200,0)
red = (200,0,0)
green_bright = (0,255,0)
red_bright = (255,0,0)



# --- functions --- 

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def crash():
    message_display("You Crashed")

def message_display():
    largeText
    text_, text_rect = text_objects(text, largeText)
    text_rect.center = ((width/2), (height/2))
    screen.blit(text_, text_rect)
    pygame.display.update()
    time.sleep(2)
    game_running()

def game_intro():

    text_vroom, text_vroom_rect = text_objects("V'Room!", largeText)
    text_vroom_rect.center = ((250),(150))

    text_go, text_go_rect = text_objects("GO", smallText)
    text_go_rect.center = ((75+(100/2)),(400+(50/2)))

    text_exit, text_exit_rect = text_objects("Exit", smallText)
    text_exit_rect.center = ((550+(100/2)),(400+(50/2)))

running = True

while running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        print(event)
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    screen.fill(blue)
    screen.blit(BackgroundPNG,(0,0))
    screen.blit(text_vroom, text_vroom_rect)

# --- Button GO ---

    if 75+100 > mouse[0] > 75 and 400+50 > mouse[1] > 400:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, green_bright,(75,400,100,50))

        if click != None and click[0] == 1:
            game_running()
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, green,(75,400,100,50))

    screen.blit(text_go, text_go_rect)

    # --- Button EXIT ---

    if 550+100 > mouse[0] > 550 and 400+50 > mouse[1] > 400:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, red_bright,(550,400,100,50))

        if click != None and click[0] == 1:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, red,(550,400,100,50))

    screen.blit(text_exit, text_exit_rect)

    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(15)

def game_running():
    print("gamerunning")

    #Create pause here
    #Create stop here
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    x = 240
    y = 280
    x_change = 0
    car_speed = 0

    crashed = False

    while not crashed:
        print(x)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            print(event)
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                crashed = True

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x_change = -50
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 50
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 0

    x += x_change

    screen.fill(blue)
    screen.blit(road, (0,0))
    screen.blit(carImg, (x,y))

    pygame.display.flip()

    if x < -10:
        x = -10
    else:
        if x > 490:
            x = 490
        else:
            crashed = False


clock.tick(30)
game_intro()
```

Comment: Please include the trace, it is invaluable for finding out what went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previous line. Parens. That is all.